# ActionBarSherlock: Programmatically show / hide Action Item buttons via a method call

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock. I wish to be able to make two buttons appear in the Action Bar in response to a certain user operation. The user operation is completely unrelated to the Action Bar. The visibility of the buttons needs to be controlled by calling a method. Also, response to clicking those buttons shall be handled by my own application code.

The buttons shall ideally look just like those that are created when defining menu items as Action Items using `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`, as illustrated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems).

My problem is that as far as I can tell, the standard `ActionBar` API provides no such mechanism to show or hide Action Item buttons at will, and the only time that the menu items can be defined is within `onCreateOptionsMenu()` which is of course called by the system.

My belief is that the only way I'm going to add buttons like this and show / hide them at will is to create a custom layout for them and make use of `.setCustomView()` to place them into the Action Bar. Would people generally agree with that, or is there something I have missed?

If I do go down the route of using `.setCustomView()`, I would like my buttons to look identical to Action Item buttons that ActionBarSherlock displays for a menu item that has the attribute `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`. To do this, can anyone advise me which particular theme, style, or layouts from within the ActionBarSherlock library I should make use of? I have already tried to use `R.layout.abs__action_menu_item_layout`, but attempting to inflate this layout produces an exception relating to a `colorStateList` when attempting inflation of the `CapitalizingButton` that the layout contains.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want those two buttons to have the look and feel of menu items, then you should make them menu items. Your assumption that menu items can only be defined in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is incorrect, because there's also a method called [`onPrepareOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29), that will be called each time right before the menu is shown. Together with an activity's [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) method, you can easily create a menu dat reflects the current state in realtime.

The alternative is to keep a reference to the individual `MenuItem` objects, as the documentation states its save to hold on to those, and change their visibility when appropriate. You may still have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to update the menu-  I can't remember from the top of my head. (**Edit:** Jake beat me to it on this one)

Personally, I prefer the first approach, since you keep all menu-related logic grouped together and the visibility is based on some sort of state/model. The second option may be more straightforward to implement, depending on your current code, but may result in menu-stuff all over the place.

Comment: Thanks, MH. There are several ideas here for which I'm grateful. There is still one issue which makes me wonder if I'll still need to resort to `.setCustomView()`. The issue is I want the text label to show always, not just icon. On my HTC One X with nothing on the ABS other than overflow icon and a single Action Item, the Action Item's text label only displays in landscape, even though there's sufficient room in either orientation. I realise that the Action Bar applies logic based on screen density and bar width to determine whether label is visible. I'll investigate this a bit more.

Comment: Juse rewrote my MenuItem logic within Fragments using advice you gave - works MUCH better now. Anyone going this way - be sure to do setHasMenuOptions(true) and go the way @MH. suggested (I do both onPrepareOptionsMenu and keeping reference to MenuItem objects).

Comment: "Personally, I prefer the first approach, since you keep all menu-related logic grouped together and the visibility is based on some sort of state/model."
Yes, together with everything else, together in the god object, called Activity. And god object is an anti pattern.

Comment: @MiklosJakab: I sincerely doubt this is the right place to venture your opinion on patterns chosen by the Android team. Anyways, regardless of which approach you choose, the menu's life cycle is tighyly bound to that of its hosting Activity. Obviously you can abstract from that to some extend, but at the end of the day, that relationship is simply the way the framework was set up. There are always pros and cons to all patterns, and many many more different openions on them. Which brings me back to my initial remark: this Q&A is probably not the right place for that dicussion. :)

Comment: @MH: Even the Google have chosen some other pattern, it is not necessarily good. And as you said one "can abstract from that to some extend". It believe driving attention to different design patterns is deeply part of the development of the common knowledge. I wouldn't like to meet completely wrong code (and i'm not saying the aforementioned one is completely wrong), but the more people reading this post the more likely I will. So it's adequate to display other opinions here.

Answer (score 11):

You can call `setVisibility` on the `MenuItem` instances.

The [documentation states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) that "You can safely hold on to menu (and any items created from it), making modifications to it as desired, until the next time onCreateOptionsMenu() is called."

Comment: Thanks, Jake (and many thanks for ABS - though you're probably tired of being thanked for it by now :-) ). As I commented to MH, one issue is that I would like to force the text labels to always show. This is one of the reasons why I may need to just apply a custom view, but I'll try some of these suggestions first.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked the demo samples ?

they have this feature there on "feature toggles" .